# Unable to print array in list form in html template variable received from javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, email, receipt

I need to show which courses user have bought and also to show them in a receipt when user receives an email. I have a node service to send emails which contain different email template in separate files and I send all the values from js file to html template, populate data in template and then send email.

Here is the code related to js file

```
  link = req.body.origin + "/contact-us";
      linkContent = "Contact Us";
      msg = msg.replace("CONTENT", " " + emailTemplate.getResetSuccessTemplate);
      var courses = ["Course1", "Course2", "Course3", "Course4"];
      msg = msg.replace("COURSES", courses);
```

Here is the html template

```
let resetPasswordSuccess = `
<ul id="myList" style="font-weight: 300;font-size: 16px;color: #4A4A4A;"></ul>

<script>
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
COURSES.split(',').forEach((item) => {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = item;
    list.appendChild(li);
});
</script>
```

I have tried to write this script code with different changes, but it does not display this array. I have used split function because this COURSES variable is received here as string.

Comment: Have you got any error to add to the question? BTW, if your replacement is a string comma-separated (because `Array.toString()` is used here under the hood), I think your template should be `'COURSES'.split(',')` or `"COURSES".split(',')` because even if you inject a string, without quotes the code generated will try to interpret it as variables or expressions here

Comment: No, there is no error. Its just that it is not displaying anything. 
And I have tried the solution that you gave, but its also not working.

Comment: Then are you sure the javascript in the template is executed at all? We don't have enough details to know if it can or not. Try adding a `console.log` or `alert` to check if so. But the simplest working solution would be to loop on `courses` and insert the `<li>` elements instead of doing a `msg.replace` with the whole array

Comment: Code is working, I tried to print it with percentage syntax and output was like this

<% Course1,Course2,Course3,Course4.split(',').forEach(function(course) { %>
<%= course %>
<% }); %>

In the email
Code was like this
<ul>
<% COURSES.split(',').forEach(function(course) { %>
  <li><%= course %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>

Comment: Then you seem to have other problems if it's not replaced in the email, and your verification confirms my first comment, `Course1,Course2,Course3,Course4.split(',')` would throw an error, the generated code should be something like `'Course1,Course2,Course3,Course4'.split(',')` (with quotes). Anyway, take a look at my answer, it would be better to replace the placeholder with html elements in your first code. Beware also that if you have multiple `COURSES` placeholders in your template, `replace` will just replace the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't rely on Javascript code to be executed or not in the email for something as trivial as this, better to inject directly the `<li>` elements in your template:

```
link = req.body.origin + "/contact-us";
linkContent = "Contact Us";
msg = msg.replace("CONTENT", " " + emailTemplate.getResetSuccessTemplate);

var courses = ["Course1", "Course2", "Course3", "Course4"];
var i, l = courses.length, str = '';
for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
    str += '<li>' + courses[i] + '</li>';
}
msg = msg.replace("COURSES", str);
```

with a simpler template like this:

```
let resetPasswordSuccess = `
<ul id="myList" style="font-weight: 300;font-size: 16px;color: #4A4A4A;">COURSES</ul>
`;
```